# JavaScript: print working directory, list files in subdirectory to console

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new to JavaScript, and am working on a website where you can upload files and display a result summary.

I've successfully uploaded the results to the webpage / on the server.

However, I am having trouble reading in an uploaded HTML file from the server ,to  load the HTML file and display it.

Below is the HTML script which prints the path to the HTML file.  but how to load the HTML i.e.  run the HTML file using javascript??

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Summary Report</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://da1s119xsxmu0.cloudfront.net/libraries/basestrap/1.0.0/css/master.min.css" />
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <h3>Summary Report</h3>
                <h4>App Results:</h4>
                <ul>

                      <h3>{{ result.name }}</h3>
        <h4>Result Files:</h4>
        <ul>
            {% for key in result.files %}
               {% if key contains '.html' %}
                <li>{{ key }}</li>

                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

## Output

The output is an unordered list of the html file on the server that I need to be read into the screen console.
1662b5e25a574e89abf2a5490005585a/expressionCSV/limmaWithMeta.html

Answer (score 0):

What is your backend running? node.js?  HTML/client side JavaScript isn't going to help you list the files uploaded to the server.  You should include the code that populates `session.results`.

In general, based on what you've mentioned about the current behavior, I'd suggest that you use a recursive function to traverse the subdirectories:

```
function listTree(root) {
  print(root);
  if (root.isDirectory()) {
    root.getFiles().forEach(function(file) {
      listTree(file);
    });
  }
}
```

As mentioned above, this would go in the server side code since that's where the files are actually stored. (Your users' computers shouldn't be able to access all the files on the server, right? :) )